# Extract shapes of curves from binary images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curves

I am analyzing back bone formation in zebrafish embryos and in this picture:

[image]
[image]

I would like to extract the shape and position of the horizontal lines/curves. Here is a little information about the image. The image at the top is already a segmented image through morphological processing and by using the MATLAB active contour function. The region between the two vertical lines is where the spinal cord develops and the horizontal lines on either side of the spinal cord later develop into ribs. The image at the bottom is where I have applied a canny edge detector. I have a time series of the development of ribs and I would now like to extract the shape and position of the horizontal curves. This is a follow up of my previous question:
[Identify curves in binary image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860236/identify-curves-in-binary-image)

I am guessing this will involve some kind of curve fitting module to obtain the shapes. Any ideas to go about this is very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I just added the pictures :) Side note: could you provide each image separately so we could work on them? thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! I just uploaded them separately.

Comment: I would: 1)Dilate the image. 2)fill the areas 3)dilate it a bit. 4)compute the morphological skeleton of the image. HAve a go at that, see if it gets you somewhere

Comment: This feels like a literal application of PoTrace by Peter Seligner, http://potrace.sourceforge.net